# What is the purpose of redirect_uri parameter when exchanging code for access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, google-openid

I am reading the Google's documentation about OpenId Connect
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

What I don't get is the purpose of the redirect_uri parameter during "4. Exchange code for access token and ID token".

The access token is returned in the response to HTTP Post request itself so I don't get the purpose of redirect_uri.

Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [oAuth spec "Access Token Request"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-4.1.3) it is mentioned that the redirect-uri is required **if** the "redirect_uri" parameter was included in the authorization request. In this case, the oauth-src checks that the uri's are identical.

Comment: That makes more sense :)